# Value of cumulative distributed function at the origin

Tags: probability-distributions

Consider  a Gaussian distributed random variable with zero mean and standard deviation sigma. The value of its commulative distributed function at theorigin will be ....

In this question, 4 options are There .out of which 0.5 is correct ans.

Is Gaussian distribution same as normal distribution ? If yes then according to the nature of graph of normal distrubution its value should be zero.

Comment: They are refering to the cdf (**cummulative** density distribution). And the cdf of a normal distribution with zero mean is $0.5$ at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $W$ be our Gaussian (normal) random variable. Then the **cumulative** distribution function $F_W(w)$ of $W$ is given by
$$F_W(w)=\Pr(W\le w).$$
Note that $F_W(w)$ is the area under the bell-shaped curve from $-\infty$ to $w$.

Our normal has mean $0$, so has density function which is symmetric about $0$. Thus the area under the bell-shaped curve from $-\infty$ to $0$ is $0.5$, and therefore
$$F_W(0)=\Pr(W\le 0)=0.5.$$

Comment: Is w the mean ?

Comment: $w$ is any number, a variable.

Comment: @akash: Maybe you thought that the cdf of $W$ at $0$ was the probability that $W$ is *equal* to $0$. The probability that $w=0$ is indeed $0$, since the normal has continuous distribution. But the cdf measures something else, the cdf at $w$ is the probability our random variable is **less than or equal** to $w$.

Comment: Sir if mean has another value except 0 then what will be the cdf

Comment: @akash: I do not understand the question, what is $p$? Maybe you could pose a specific question with specific numbers, then I can try to answer it. Make $\sigma$ specific too, since the answer may depend on it. (It didn't for the question you actually asked.)

Comment: Sir I've asked if mean has its another value except zero.

Comment: Then what will be its cdf..

Comment: If $W$ is normal with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, then $F_W(w)=\Pr(W\le w)=\Pr\left(Z\le \frac{w-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$, where $Z$ is the standard normal. For any reasonable $z$, $\Pr(Z\le z)$ can be found by using a table of the standard normal. The cdf of $W$ can also be expressed as an integral, but for the normal that is not terribly computationally useful.

Comment: @akash: About chat, I had a couple of negative experiences, so no longer use it. But I am perfectly willing to answer questions in comments, as long as the answers can be kept short. (Typing math in comments is difficult, since editing facilities are poor, and there are limits on length and layout.)